# How to make collisions occur between objects using the same script?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, car, prefabs

Well what I’m trying to do is have cars travelling on the road. The cars have a trigger at the front and a hitbox at the back of the cars. What I want to happen is when the trigger hits the hitbox it compares the Variables for speed of the two cars in the collision, i.e. the make the car at the back slow down or equal the speed of the car in the front. However, what I am having trouble with is referencing the speed of both cars and comparing them. This is due to them both being prefabs using the same script. Which I’m learning means that I’m just referencing the same script and not the actual values of the individual car. But how could I get round this? Is it possible to have collisions occurring between objects using the same script?

```
    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("TriggerStay");


        GameObject collidedParent = collision.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject; // get parent transform and then its gameobject
        Traffic Col_speed = collidedParent.GetComponent<Traffic>();


        if (speed > Col_speed.speed)
        {
            Accelerate = false;
            ApplyBreak = true;
        }
        else if (speed < Col_speed.speed)
        {
            Accelerate = false;
            ApplyBreak = false;
            speed = Col_speed.speed;
        }

        if (transform.position.y > collision.transform.position.y)
        {
            turn = turn + 1;
            Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name + "someMessage");

        }
        if (transform.position.y < collision.transform.position.y)
        {
            turn = turn - 1;
            Col_speed.turn = 0;
            Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name + "someMessage");

        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        turn = 0;
        Accelerate = true;
        ApplyBreak = false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you are not actually referencing the scripts but its intances. Each of your script components it technically already an instance of the script which means it can have its own values. In other words: You can have many cars using the same scripts. They individually do what the scripts tell them. They are instances and thats why it's even possible to have multiple cars that do individual things.

Your line

```
Traffic Col_speed = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Traffic>();
```

should already get the instance of the other (collding) car so the `Col_speed.speed` is the other cars speed.

I hope this clears things up but what is your actual issue? -> describe what you expect but what happens instead, then the community can provide further help.

Edit:

As of your comments, to get the Traffic component from the parent you can do:

```
...
GameObject collidedParent = collision.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject; // get parent transform and then its gameobject
Traffic Col_speed = collidedParent.GetComponent<Traffic>();
...
```

Note that this approach will stop working if you change the gameObject hierarchy.

Comment: Well I'm glad i'm actually coding for the instance correctly. The issue is that i'm getting a error message saying "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object TriggerHit.OnTriggerStay2D " for the line: ```if (speed > Col_speed.speed)``` so something is wrong

Comment: Are the collider component and the `Traffic` ScriptComponent attached to the same gameObject? Or is one on the parent and one on a child gameObject? This would explain why the Traffic component cannot be found on the colliding gameObject.

Comment: The Traffic ScriptComponent is attached to the parent, whilst the collider component is attached on a child gameObject.

Comment: Thats why you are getting the error. The `GetComponent<Traffic>()` call searches the child gameObject (the one with the collider). Since there is no Traffic component on this gameObject, it returns null. Then when you try to get the `speed` on that null reference you get the `NullReferenceException`. To avoid this the simplest way is to do: `collision.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<Traffic>()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That’s great thanks, your explanation makes so much sense and I’m no longer getting a null reference. However, I’m having another issue. The variables I am changing is applying to both objects that are collided. I don’t want it to apply to the collision object.

Comment: To answer this you probably need to provide more of the code. My two guesses are either the `speed` variable is `static` or both objects are colliding with eachothers triggers and therefore both execute the code you showed.

Comment: I've updated the code above in my question. My speed variable is public and when i view  the inspector the triggers are not colliding with each other.

Comment: when i run the code both cars turn in the opposite direction, when I only want one car to turn

Comment: What I mean is that during runtime, the cars might collide in a way that both execute the `OnTriggerStay2D` method. If they are front-to-back collisions only, make sure one of the cars colliders is marked as trigger and the other is not. Otherwise you would need to implement a way to decide which of the cars should turn and which car should go straight.

Comment: What I have done is put two colliders on the car. One at the front and one on the back. Only the front collider is set as a trigger as I want this car to turn.

Comment: It is really hard to guess without full insight. How do your variable declarations for `speed`, `turn`, `Accelerate` and `ApplyBreak` look like? Something is making your other car turn. Either from within the OnTriggerStay or from somewhere else where `turn` is modified? However in the provided code, turn is never used to control the car.. You should debug the behaviour to find what turns the other car. You can do this by adding `Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name + "someMessage");` statements and find out if (and when) a cars trigger method is called (assuming they have different names).

Comment: I've added the other code so you can see how it is implemented. Is this not due to both cars using the same script? both cars have the same name so I can't debug

Comment: You *need* to debug, it's key. You can temporarly change the cars names. Also I cannot see where the named properties are declared and the first part will likely not compile as you pasted it now. It might have to do with the inheritance you are using (TriggerHit : Traffic) is there a reason for this? As I said, if done correctly, both cars (A and B) have their own instance of the script so therefore car B should not be affected if a property of car A is changed (unless that property is really a static variable or leaked otherwise).

Comment: I've gotten rid of the Triggerhit class and pasted the code now into the traffic class. Can see the code above. this has stopped both cars turning however its turning the wrong car, the car in the front of the collision not the one at the back.

Comment: also how could i rename the cars

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107077/discussion-between-schneebuzz-and-user2773611).